# SMartGWT TileGrid horizontal overflow only

Tags: grid, overflow, smartgwt, tile

Using SMartGWT I created a TileGrid, and now I'm trying to set the Overflow parameter in a way such that if there is overflow the scrollbar appears only for the Horizontal navigation and not the vertical one.
There are basically 4 slots for the tiles and if I add a 5th one, only the scroll bar for vertical navigation is shown.
In other words I want that the overflow is inline

I already tried these possibilities, but no one works.

```
setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO) 
setOverflow(Overflow.CLIP_V) 
setOverflow(Overflow.CLIP_H) 
setOverflow(Overflow.SCROLL)
```

I also tried with the CSS code

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the orientation for the TileGrid to vertical by

```
setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

With this, you will get all tiles in one line. Sometimes a small vertical scrollbar still appears because the horizontal scrollbar. In this case you should also play with the settings and sizes to see only a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change. Neither using Vertical or Horizontal. But I found another solution for my layout! Thx a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem here. The only solution I've found for now was:

1) Set the tilesPerLine property of TileGrid to a big value.

2) Set the orientation property of TileGrid to "horizontal".